# Populating map of String to Spring beans of a common interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, factory

In my Spring boot application, I have an interface as follows:

```
 public interface I {
    
 }
```

I have two concrete classes implementing the interface `I` as follows:

```
 @Component
 class A implements I {
     private final B dependency1;
     
     public A(B b) {
         this.dependency1 = b;
     }
 }
```

And second class as follows:

```
@Compeonent
class C implements I {
     private final D dependency2;
     
     public C(D d) {
         this.dependency2 = d;
     }
 }
```

Now in a factory class, I am building a map to get the object of specific class depending on some criteria as follows:

```
  class Factory {

 
  Map<String, I> criteriaToClassMap = new HashMap<>();

  criteriaToClassMap.put("criteria1", new A()); <--I CANNOT DECIDE WHAT TO PUT HERE
  criteriaToClassMap.put("criteria2", new C()); <--I CANNOT DECIDE WHAT TO PUT HERE

   //Here I would like to get fully constructed object
   public I getObject(String criteria) {
       return criteriaToClassMap.get(criteria);
   }
}
```

In the above two lines, I would like to put a fully constructed object in the value. But I cannot understand how will I get the fully constructed object from Spring here.

Could anyone please help here?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? `new A()` won't work since you don't have no-args contructor

Comment: @Aman The ultimate goal is to get a fully constructed object from this factory. I would like to get the object constructed by Spring, if possible.

Comment: Since factory is creational pattern and spring already creates singleton for all components, I dont think it will be nice to do so. but. if you insist I suppose you have to autowire them  not create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the created components?

```java
@Component
class Factory {

   Map<String, I> criteriaToClassMap = new HashMap<>();

   public Factory (A a, C c) {
       criteriaToClassMap.put("criteria1", a); //<-- use autowired A component
       criteriaToClassMap.put("criteria2", c); //<-- use autowired C component
   }

   public I getObject(String criteria) {
       return criteriaToClassMap.get(criteria);
   }

}
```